# mySQL Query count, select three tables

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hope I can get some help with this problem.   I have three tables, one has posts (ideas) called op_ideas.  I have another table which is called op_idea_votes.  These can be linked by idea_id.

when an idea is posted, folk can vote on the idea. op_idea_votes is then updated with the latest vote.

I then have another table called op_organs, which may or may not be empty depending on what user type posted.  So this table is linked by POST_TYPE (which is the id for op_organs table) to op_organs.organ_id.

I need to select all these tables to create a row with all the info to display, which need to be linked by idea_id, and post_type.  But I also need COUNT on 3 of the columns on op_idea_vote table (agree, disagree, abstain).

I have tired UNION, SELECT with SUM(CASE, but I cannot get the desired affect. LEFT and INNER JOIN's but I seem to get something wrong, as part or all of the info is missing.

The app is in javascript and PHP, so I am trying to lessen the number of calls to the database and to the PHP file (with ajax) where the query is, which is why I am trying to do it one go.   Thou if there is a better way I am all ears.

This is the current attempt created from a tool, but it comes back empty, but no error:

```
SELECT
op_ideas.author_id,
op_ideas.date,
op_ideas.deptid,
op_ideas.idea_geo,
op_ideas.idea_id,
op_ideas.idea_text,
op_ideas.idea_title,
op_ideas.modifed_date,
op_ideas.post_type,
op_ideas.user_country,
op_ideas.user_county,
op_ideas.user_loc,
op_organs.organ_name,
op_organs.organ_logo,
op_organs.active,
COUNT(op_idea_vote.agree),
COUNT(op_idea_vote.disagree),
COUNT(op_idea_vote.obstain)
FROM
heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas op_ideas,
heroku_056eb661631f253.op_organs op_organs,
heroku_056eb661631f253.op_idea_vote op_idea_vote
WHERE
op_ideas.idea_id = op_idea_vote.idea_id AND
op_ideas.post_type = op_organs.organs_id
```

So the data would look like this:

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| idea_id | author_id | idea_title | idea_text | date | agree | disagree | abstain | organ_name | organ_logo
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 00001 | 10025225 | teste title | text here | 2012| 00005 | 0000004 | 000002 | Comp Name | image/.png
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Not a great example. But I tried.

Here is the latest code.  It brings back the 3 rows, even if op_organs is null.  But it does not show the votes count:

```
  SELECT i.*, o.organ_name, o.organ_logo
  FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas i
  LEFT JOIN op_organs o ON i.post_type = o.organs_id
  JOIN 
    (SELECT
       COUNT(v.agree = 1 or null) as agree,
       COUNT(v.disagree = 1 or null) as disagree,
       COUNT(v.obstain = 1 or null) as abstain
       FROM op_idea_vote v, op_ideas i
       GROUP BY v.idea_id
   ) as votes;
```

Spent all day on this, read so much my head is spinning.  Anyone have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear exactly what output you desire.  Perhaps some example data and the desired output would help?

Comment: I need a row containing the fields above. But note, op_organs could be null, and I need to count the fields in op_idea_vote based on each record in op_ideas.   I will edit the top and try and visualise it.

Comment: when you use count, select will be always 1 row. So you should try to select all data into one row see GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    op_ideas.author_id,
    op_ideas.date,
    op_ideas.deptid,
    op_ideas.idea_geo,
    op_ideas.idea_id,
    op_ideas.idea_text,
    op_ideas.idea_title,
    op_ideas.modifed_date,
    op_ideas.post_type,
    op_ideas.user_country,
    op_ideas.user_county,
    op_ideas.user_loc,
    op_organs.organ_name,
    op_organs.organ_logo,
    op_organs.active,
    COUNT(op_idea_vote.agree = 1 or null) as agrees,
    COUNT(op_idea_vote.disagree = 1 or null) as disagrees,
    COUNT(op_idea_vote.obstain = 1 or null) as absteins
FROM
    heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas op_ideas,
    left join
    heroku_056eb661631f253.op_organs op_organs on op_ideas.post_type = op_organs.organs_id,
    inner join 
    heroku_056eb661631f253.op_idea_vote op_idea_vote on op_ideas.idea_id = op_idea_vote.idea_id
group by
    op_ideas.author_id,
    op_ideas.date,
    op_ideas.deptid,
    op_ideas.idea_geo,
    op_ideas.idea_id,
    op_ideas.idea_text,
    op_ideas.idea_title,
    op_ideas.modifed_date,
    op_ideas.post_type,
    op_ideas.user_country,
    op_ideas.user_county,
    op_ideas.user_loc,
    op_organs.organ_name,
    op_organs.organ_logo,
    op_organs.active
```

Comment: I didn't know one could short-circuit the boolean operators like that (it's undocumented though, so perhaps not reliable?).  I usually do `SUM(condition)` in MySQL or `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0)` elsewhere.

Comment: @Colodaldo Thank you, i did not get any errors, but I had no results and I should have three ?

Comment: @eggyal  I changed it to SUM(CASE:  
`SUM(CASE WHEN op_idea_vote.agree THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as agrees,
SUM(CASE WHEN op_idea_vote.disagree THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as disagree,
SUM(CASE WHEN op_idea_vote.obstain THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as obstain`

But still no results ?

Comment: @AndrewWalker I change it. Try again

Comment: I have this now `SELECT *,
SUM(CASE op_idea_vote.idea_id = op_ideas.idea_id WHEN op_idea_vote.agree = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as agree,
SUM(CASE op_idea_vote.idea_id = op_ideas.idea_id WHEN op_idea_vote.disagree = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as disagree,
SUM(CASE op_idea_vote.idea_id = op_ideas.idea_id WHEN op_idea_vote.obstain = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as obstain 
FROM heroku_056eb661631f253.op_ideas
    left join
    heroku_056eb661631f253.op_organs on op_ideas.post_type = op_organs.organs_id
left join 
    heroku_056eb661631f253.op_idea_vote on op_ideas.idea_id = op_idea_vote.idea_id` i get 1 record

Comment: Also tried `    COUNT(op_idea_vote.agree = 1 or null) as agrees,
    COUNT(op_idea_vote.disagree = 1 or null) as disagrees,
    COUNT(op_idea_vote.obstain = 1 or null) as absteins`  Again just one record returned (should be 3)?